# how to animate a css grandient change with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, gradient

I want to animate a css gradient with jquery and I can't find any solution. Does anyone have an idea ? The thing is, I can't animate from a class to another because my rgba is random (Ive made a little something using mousemouve event).

Here is my actual code

```
$(this).css(
     {background: '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba('+ a +','+ b +','+ c +','+ alpha +')), to(rgba('+ a2 +','+ b2 +','+ c2 +','+ alpha +')))'
});
```

But what I want to do would be something like this :

```
$(this).stop().animate(
            {background: '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba('+ a +','+ b +','+ c +','+ alpha +')), to(rgba('+ a2 +','+ b2 +','+ c2 +','+ alpha +')))'},
            {
                duration:   1500, 
                easing:     'easeOutBounce'
            }
        );
```

The best I got was that it doesn't change the gradient but only the background color with the first rgba.

Basically, the css() is too aggressive, I want it to be smooth. I tried to use animate with the backgroundcolor only and it works fine, but not the gradient.

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** Here is the full js [background.js](http://lekalif.com/data/js/background.js)

**EDIT #2** : Find all my answers here. [script on jqueryscript.net](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Creating-Animated-Background-with-Random-Gradient-Transitions-using-jQuery.html)

Comment: You're not going to be able to do with with jQuery.animate() but you could write a straight javascript implementation using setInterval().

Comment: Tried css `transitions` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions ? Or , utilizing `step` function within `.animate` ?

Comment: @guest271314 the transitions don't work with gradient. I don't know step to be frank :) is it a plugin or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, Not certain if the syntax , order of

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba()), to(rgba()))
```

is accurate ? See [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) , [Using Gradients](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/internetweb/conceptual/safarivisualeffectsprogguide/Gradients/Gradient.html) . At piece below , changed to

```
-webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba(), rgba())
```

Also, the `easing` option `easeOutBounce` not appear to be standard within `jquery` ; require either [jquery ui](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/) , or [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) . Added jquery ui to scripts loaded.

jquery's `.animate()` may need a "color" plugin to animate color `properties` . Though , can utilize the `step` function , within `.animate()`'s `options` , to perform tasks for each "step" of the animation , see

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) , at `step`

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated
>   element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween
>   object to change the value of the property before it is set.

The `properties` , here , is defined with `border:"0"` - though , with jquery ui color animations appear possible [Color Animation](http://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/) - `step` function utilized at piece below.

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").mousemove(function (event) {

        var sw = $(window).width(),
            sh = $(window).height(),
            valueX = event.pageX,
            valueY = event.pageY;

        var fX = (valueX / sw),
            fY = (valueY / sh);

        var alpha = ((fX / 2) + (fY / 2));

        var r = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 100)))),
            g = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 100)))),
            b = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 100)))),
            r2 = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)))),
            g2 = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)))),
            b2 = Math.round(((Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1))));

        console.log('x:' + fX + ' - y:' + fY + '');
        console.log('rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + alpha + ')');
        console.log('rgba2(' + r2 + ',' + g2 + ',' + b2 + ',' + alpha + ')');

        // animate the background color on mousemove
        $(event.target).stop().animate({
            border:"0"
        }, {
            duration: 1500
            , easing: 'easeOutBounce'
            , step: function() {
              $(this).css('background'
                          ,'-webkit-linear-gradient(left top, rgba('
                          + r +','+ g +','+ b +','
                          + alpha +'), rgba('
                          + r2 +','+ g2 +','+ b2 +','+ alpha +')')
        }
        });

    });
});
```

```css
body {
    width : 646px;
    height : 615px;
    background-color : transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/vystqodj/

Comment: Thanks a lot, works great. Do you have any idea how can I render it less "hard". I mean, if I wanted to do something like : When I move, it doesn't change, till I stop and then it change with a duration ?

Comment: Yeah, indeed :) The thing is. I still can't make it as smooth as a animate() with background color. But I guess, I can't to do it since jquery doesn't animate webkit-gradient

Comment: @hellodracon Could possibly include css `transition` or `animation` (`keyframes`) into piece ; or utilize http://api.jqueryui.com/color-animation/ ; to find the desired color-transition effects

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this. Thanks again for everything !

Answer (score 1):

CSS is the best approach here. Add the necessary transition/animation to the element. Have several classes with different background gradients and then use jQuery to add/remove the classes as necessary. To my knowledge, CSS gradient backgrounds do not animate via `transition`. You will likely need to use `keyframe` animations. You may need animation callbacks as well to make sure the animations don't jump if they are based on mouse events (hover, click, etc). It would probably be fairly difficult to implement a smooth solution with mouse events.

See http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/animating-css3-gradients for examples of keyframe gradient animations. One trick many people use is changing the background position, not the gradient itself. In that situation, transition can work.

Alternatively, jQuery Transit (http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) could possibly do it, but untested and not documented.

Comment: Hi, the thing is, I can't create classes because my rgba is created by mousemove only. So the only way I have would be to find a way to animate css(). Here is my actual full javascript :
[link](http://lekalif.com/data/js/background.js)